# Do you need the [minecraft] tag for [minecraft-commands] or [minecraft-redstone] tag questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, minecraft, sub-tags

Recently, I have noticed a lot of Minecraft questions are being edited mainly concerning tags.

There are cases where the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag is being added (in the edits) to questions that are specifically regarding commands.  For example:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/205490
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/205489

I was under the impression that each tag was a distinct area of knowledge.  Therefore, if a question is scoped to only cover Minecraft commands expertise, does it need the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag?  Does adding the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag do more harm?  Does this affect people who follow the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag but want to avoid [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands), [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) or other sub-tags?

Should I continue to reject these edit suggestions?

Comment: So one of my questions was just edited in a similar manner, except a tag was also removed ([tag:Minecraft-commands]), which is actually quite important to the question. The edit should have been rejected or improved.

Comment: @MBraedley - this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/205729 ?

Comment: Real quick comment because it's late (or early) and I want to sleep: Ideally, Yes, use both. A question about Minecraft commands is still a question about Minecraft, it's just a subcategory that the community decided is large enough that it should be logically grouped together. It also helps those ignoring tags: someone ignoring [Minecraft] will likely also want to ignore [Minecraft-commands], but unless we tag with both, they will have to manually ignore the subtags as well.

Comment: @camelCase yes that's it.  Would have found it myself if I wasn't limited to my phone

Answer (score 4):

Since Robotnik didn't provide a full answer...

No, you should not be rejecting these edits.  The [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag is useful to these questions because our default tagging scheme is to tag a question with the game.  Minecraft is that game, so there is no reason for that tag to not be there.  (Mea culpa, there is at least one instance (mentioned above) where I didn't include the base Minecraft tag.)

In addition to Robotnik's suggestion that those who ignore [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) would probably also ignore [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) and [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) (let's forget for a moment that this can be accomplished by ignoring `minecraft*`), some users might find it beneficial to favorite [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) while ignoring [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands), since they have no interest or experience in command blocking.  In general, the logical conclusion that you should draw from this argument is to not tag those questions with the base Minecraft tag; however, the interaction between favorite and ignored tags means that it'll still be obvious to the user that this is a question that they're not interested in, and no harm is done by having the multiple tags.

Now, on to the issue I brought up, which is suggested edits that remove a Minecraft sub tag (or any other sub tag that exists) that should be there.  These edits should, at the very least, be improved to undo the harm being done by the removal of the tag, or rejected in order to send a clear message to the suggester that what they've done is wrong and reapplied with the correct tags.  It is unclear to me how the reviewers allowed this to happen, other than the possibility that they didn't know that [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) also encompassed command blocks (although that is in the wiki excerpt).